# How to parse 2 different JSONArray into 1 ListView

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a problem that needs some help, I have the following json file from my server. For now as a temporary solution,  I created 2 different views,xmls,getter & setters,adapters by following this [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSX4zIhiZlM) tutorial.
I was wondering if there is anyone to guide or teach me how to combine the both of them together as I am still learning Android.

I am trying to combine both apifrom and apito into 1 listView and arrange them accordingly to the date_time

Below is my JSON response from the server.

**JSON Response**

```
{
  "apifrom": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "from_account": "Account2",
      "to_account": "Cash",
      "amount": "4394.0",
      "date_time": "2016-02-26T09:17:51.518Z"
      }
  ],
  "apito": [
    {
      "id": 189,
      "from_account": "Account1",
      "to_account": "Account2",
      "amount": "1200.0",
      "date_time": "2016-03-24T08:19:23.846Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: parse your json response and store it to one arraylist and set that arraylist to your listview adapter

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this!

```
JSONObject jsonRes = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
JSONArray jsonArr1 = jsonRes.getJSONArray("apiTo");
JSONArray jsonArr2 = jsonRes.getJSONArray("apiFrom");
```

After this, you can parse the both JSON array, make the object of that, and pass it to an ArrayList

```
List<ItemObject> jsonObject = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
//then Add object to arraylist
jsonObject.add(ParsedJsonObject);
```

To combine both JSONArray, you can try something like this :

```
    private JSONArray concatArray(JSONArray arr1, JSONArray arr2)
        throws JSONException {
    JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length(); i++) {
        result.put(arr1.get(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length(); i++) {
        result.put(arr2.get(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

set this in your adapter of your ListView. Hope this helps!

Comment: `apiTo` and `apiFrom` both are `JSONArray` not `JSONObject`. Please update your answer to parse both `JSONArray`.

Comment: True updating it @pRaNaY

Comment: Hi Ajay, I don't quite get you, after creating jsonArr2, what am I suppose to do?because at my java file, after creating the jsonArr, it will be a while loop to loop through the length and add the json data into my listview.

Comment: parse the JSONArray, and then make an object of it, and add in arrayList. its simple! @iOSAndroid

Answer (score 0):

Define your own Bean object, and you can put any different JSONArray into your bean. After that, use

```
ArrayList<YourBean>
```

as your ListView's data source.

After all, JSONArray is data module, ListView is UI component, you can always define your own relations between them.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do that, either you can take arraylist of hashmap and create new hashmap each new record,or you can take arraylist of POJO class.

```
public class POJOclas {
    public String name,id;

}
```

Use Arraylist like this way

```
public ArrayList<POJOclas> mypojocls= new ArrayList<POJOclas>();
```

and then insert data in arraylist